# How can I hide an iframe on click using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

There is  a video playing when the user enters my website and when the video is clicked I would like to hide the iframe and show the menu page. Can someone help me with this?
This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu-page").hide();
    $("#SiteNav").hide();
    $("#filecontainer").on("click",function(){
        $("#menu-page").show();
        $("#SiteNav").show();
        $("#filecontainer").hide();
    });
 });
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box">
<div class="main-video">
<iframe id="filecontainer" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NQokQxdFVqE?autoplay=1&amp;mute=1&amp;playlist=NQokQxdFVqE&amp;loop=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" width="1920" height="1042" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
</div>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: well you can not detect a click inside of the iframe since it is in another domain.

Comment: You can use the [YouTube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) to detect when a video starts playing, then invoke whatever logic you want to perform.

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to be able to detect a click in the iframe. You can add a layer over the page and detect that click and hide it that way.

```js
$(".layer").on("click", function () {
  $(".layer, #filecontainer").remove();
});
```

```css
.layer{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left:0; height: 100%; width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="box">
<div class="main-video">
<iframe id="filecontainer" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NQokQxdFVqE?autoplay=1&amp;mute=1&amp;playlist=NQokQxdFVqE&amp;loop=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" width="1920" height="1042" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
</div>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
<div class="layer"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @epascarello but I forgot to mention that when the user enters the website, there is a blur screen that the user can wipe on mousemove and that would reveal the video playing on the background. Would the layer also work?

Comment: not sure why it would not.... hard to guess without knowing anything about it.

Comment: Your code  works only if I use layer over the video but I have a canvas over layer/video, once I erase the canvas on mouse move a video is playing on the background and when I click on the layer it should show the menu and hide the video and canvas but it doesn't work can you maybe help me with this?

Comment: So you stick the layer under the layer you have for the mouse move

Comment: that's what I did but when I click nothing happends :(